# regex to select a tag and which contains text beside it without any space

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, regex

This is the text

```
Tutorial<del class="del">Within word</del>WordEnd sample <del class="del">total word</del> Welcome to the site!
```

I am trying to write regex to select tag `<del>` and anything between `<del></del>` and text beside it, but only select those `<del>` tags which do not have space between the tag and the preceding text.

For example in the above text - `Tutorial<del class="del">Within word</del>WordEnd` must get selected. But `<del class="del">total word</del> Welcome` must not get selected, as there is a space between  and Welcome.

Anyone please help. Thanks in advance !!

Comment: is it del tag only???

Comment: yes. Regex must select between <del> </del> tag along with the text preceding outside the tag, but only that text which has no space between the tag and the text

Comment: Trying to parse HTML using regex? This won't end well...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Final attempt:

```
"/(\w+<del.*?>.*?(<\/del>\w+|<\/del>))|(<del.*?>.*?<\/del>\w+)/g"
```

https://regex101.com/r/mD8zF7/10

Comment: This is some what correct. For the text with no space it is checking both ends of start tag <del> and end tag </del>. But either there is no space before start tag or no space after end tag it must select. No need to check both the conditions that there must be no space between any of the start or end tags. If there is no space between any one tag also it must select

Comment: That's correct. But please check this. When I try to give the text like something in the link. Everything is getting mixed up. regex is not working property in the case given in the link https://regex101.com/r/mD8zF7/4

Comment: For that text its correct. But again when I tried to change the text to https://regex101.com/r/mD8zF7/7. The regex is again reflecting wrong output

Comment: Final go before I admit defeat, answer updated - Nope still not working, sorry, at my limit of regex knowledge

Comment: please look into this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38869675/correction-in-regex

Answer (score -1):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
/([^\s]+)(\<del)(.*?)(\<\/del\>)([^\s]+)/
```

Example: https://regex101.com/r/sL8jV8/1

If you're looking for multiple matches in a string (above is just 1) use this one:

```
/([^\s]+)(\<del)(.*?)(\<\/del\>)([^\s]+)/g
```

Example: https://regex101.com/r/hE6dH4/1

Comment: This is some what correct. For the text with no space it is checking both ends of start tag <del> and end tag </del>. But either there is no space before start tag or no space after end tag it must select. No need to check both the conditions that there must be no space between any of the start or end tags. Any one tag also it must select

Comment: please look into this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38869675/correction-in-regex