# Correction in regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a content which has content along with HTML tags inside the content. I am trying to identify `<ins></ins>` and `<del></del>` with the conditions mentioned in this image

[image: Conditions]

The regex is

```
/((?=(\w*))\2(?:(?:\w*(?:<del\b[^>]*>(?:(?!<\/del>).)*<\/del>)|\w*(?:<ins\b[^>]*>\w+<\/ins>)|(?:\w+<\/ins>)|(?:<ins\b[^>]*>\w+))(?:\w+|))+)/g
```

URL : https://regex101.com/r/cE4mE3/30

It is failing in only single case, that is when there an HTML tag or special character inside `<ins></ins>` its not identifying correctly. In the above regex there is a `</ins></ins>` inside another `<ins></ins>` and hence it is breaking before the start of open `<ins>` tag. The regex identification must stop only when there is fullstop or comma or space between an `<ins></ins>`. But if there is any HTML tag or another `<ins></ins>` tag itself inside another `<ins></ins>` the identification must continue.

In the above regex the groups which are to be selected are :

```
<ins class="ins">ff</ins><del class="del">C</del>om<del class="del"> </del><ins class="ins"><ins class="ins">g</ins></ins><del class="del"> g</del>gp<del class="del">a</del>n<del class="del">y</del>
```

And

```
test<del class="del">test</del><ins class="ins">tik</ins><del class="del">peop</del>man<del class="del"> </del></i><del class="del"> g</del>gp<del class="del">a</del>n<del class="del">y</del>
```

But as there are HTML tags between the identification is stopping near the HTML tag in 1 and 2 groups.

Comment: Haven't I seen this question repeatetly posted with different by different accounts?

Comment: The content might be same because all it contains is <ins> and <del> tags, but the question is different

Comment: Can you simplify the explanation of what you're trying to match or replace?

Comment: @sln I am trying to match <ins class="ins">ff</ins><del class="del">C</del>om<del class="del"> </del><ins class="ins"><ins class="ins">g</ins></ins><del class="del"> g</del>gp<del class="del">a</del>n<del class="del">y</del> but in this part these is a <ins></ins> inside another <ins></ins> hence the match has stopped near <ins class="ins">ff</ins><del class="del">C</del>om<del class="del"> </del>

Comment: You have a lot of qualifications with the content. Can you explain the open/close paradigm of the _tags_. This is actually more important than the content stuff...

Comment: "simplify the explanation" *replied to with endless HTML tags*

Comment: the other match should be test<del class="del">test</del><ins class="ins">tik</ins><del class="del">peop</del>man<del class="del"> </del></i><del class="del"> g</del>gp<del class="del">a</del>n<del class="del">y</del> but now it is test<del class="del">test</del><ins class="ins">tik</ins><del class="del">peop</del>man<del class="del"> </del> because there is HTML tag i.e, <i> tag in between so the match stopped near <i> tag

Comment: If I was 5 years old, how would you explain it? Do you want to match all `<del>` and `<ins>` tags? Then what do you want to do, get their content? Delete it if it's between `<del>` and something else between `<ins>` (assuming some sort of insert)?

Comment: @NickBull not all, based on conditions which I have explained in diagram http://i.stack.imgur.com/8iNWl.png. The only modification which has to be done in current regex https://regex101.com/r/cE4mE3/30 is, if there is a space or comma or fullstop between <ins></ins> tag then only the match has to stop. If there is HTML tag or another <ins> or </ins> in between set of <ins></ins> the match must continue over these

Comment: `If there is HTML tag of another <ins> or </ins> in between set of <ins></ins> the match must continue over these` This kills regex for you. JavaScript can't do recursion in ECmaScript regex engine. PHP can though. Sorry, there is no solution for you..

Comment: sorry its not "of" its "or" in "If there is HTML tag or <ins> or </ins> in between set of <ins></ins> the match must continue over these"

Comment: This is the key phrase -> `another <ins> or </ins> in between set of <ins></ins>` and still no recursion available in JS. Wthout recursion, there is no way to _pair_ a set of open/close tags. When I say _recursion_ I'm talking about a STACK !

Comment: if there is no solution for this can I get a regex to identify only the <ins></ins> which has another <ins></ins> inside it. For example "<ins>word word<ins>word </ins></ins>"

Comment: please do not use regex for html, if you have jquery, use that instead